# SQL connection c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a standart local Oracle DB to which i can connect with my sqldeveloper
using connection with :

```
username = system
password = orcl
hostname = localhost
port = 1521 
SID = ORCL
```

but when i'm trying to do this in the code

```
try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                builder.DataSource = "localhost";
                builder.InitialCatalog = "HR_ORCL";
                builder.UserID = "system";
                builder.Password = "orcl";
                string connectionString = "Server=(local);Database=HR_ORCL;User ID=system;Password=orcl";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

                    connection.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
                    Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
                        connection.ConnectionString);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
            }
```

I'm getting an error

> "provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL server"

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: And you question is?

Comment: I've added an error.

Comment: You are using SQL server classes to connect to Oracle database. You should install ODAC with ODT for visual studio and use Oracle Managed Driver. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly said by Stefan you need to download and install [ODP from this site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Once the installation is done you need to add a reference of the assembly Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

And then you can use it like this:

```
using System; 
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 

class MyClass
{ 
    OracleConnection con; 
    void Connect() 
    { 
        con = new OracleConnection(); 
        con.ConnectionString = "yourconnectionstring"; 
        con.Open(); 
    }

    void Close() 
    {
        con.Close(); 
        con.Dispose(); 
    } 

    static void Main() 
    { 
        //some code
    } 
}
```